# Chaining Rendering Transformations: Making isotherms using Barnes Surface + Contour process?

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to calculate isotherms following the istructions showed in the post on OSGeo blog (http://blog.opengeo.org/2013/01/10/chaining-rendering-transformations-in-geoserver/)

I'm using GeoServer 2.2.3 on a Windows 7 machine (8 Gbyte RAM, biprocessor)

I've a shapefile with points and temperature  and I'm trying to use the Meteo-1.sld

Using the layer in preview

http://:8080/geoserver/CesareWorkspace/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=CesareWorkspace:CentralineTemperature-01-01-2001&styles=&bbox=318287.0,4880823.0,515945.0,5142603.0&width=386&height=512&srs=EPSG:32632&format=application/openlayers

it works fine but when I try to use le Meteo-1.sld

http://:8080/geoserver/CesareWorkspace/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=CesareWorkspace:CentralineTemperature-01-01-2001&styles=&bbox=318287.0,4880823.0,515945.0,5142603.0&width=386&height=512&srs=EPSG:32632&format=application/openlayers&STYLES=Meteo-1

the map is white. It seems that there are no errors in the log.

When I try to use the  Barnes Surface WPS directy (gs.BarnesSurface),  I obtain a black tiff ....

At the following link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fmbdhzwp5mobpcq/lf43d3SykM there are:

- data.zip --> the shapefile I'm using
- Meteo-1.sld --> the sld I'm  using
- geoserver.log --> geoserver log

Could someone tell me which configurations I've to use in the sld  for my data? Or give me a sample data and a sld that works?

Answer (score 2):

I worked a little bit on this issue and now I'm able to obtain something that works (still not a final work but it's fine ....).

At the following link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fmbdhzwp5mobpcq/lf43d3SykM there are:

```
TemperatureBand.sld --> SLD to generate a temperature band surface
Isotherm.sld --> SLD ti generate isotherm from the temperature band surface
TemeperatureBand-Isothem --> SLD "all in one"
```

It seems better: try to creare a Group Layer using the point, the surface and the isothems and it looks better now.