# Creating Contours via SLD using the Barnes Surface interpolation in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld, contour

I am trying to make a map with PostGIS and GeoServer, showing weather data. The data that I have is pointdata from observation stations.

The data is vectordata. With an SLD using the Barnes Surface rendering transformation I get the following WMS output (OpenLayers preview): [image]

Now i want to add contour lines. Of course that is a Raster-to-Vector rendering transformation. I read that it should be possible to use the Barnes Surface transformation as input for my contour transformation. But I cannot find how to do this. There is very little documentation about this.

I only found this question: [Chaining Rendering Transformations: Making isotherms using Barnes Surface + Contour process?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48870/chaining-rendering-transformations-making-isotherms-using-barnes-surface-cont), but the site that is referenced is not even online anymore and there is not really a clear answer.

The SLD documentation says that it is possible to use multiple rendering transformations, but I do not know how to code it. Can anybody help with that? What am I doing wrong?

Below the SLD code that I am working with now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<NamedLayer> 
    <Name> BarnesContours </Name> 
        <UserStyle> 
        <Title> Barnes Surface Contours </Title> 
        <Abstract> Extracts from a computed surface </Abstract> 
  <FeatureTypeStyle> 
   <Transformation>
     <ogc:Function name="vec:BarnesSurface">
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>valueAttr</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Literal>ff</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>scale</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Literal>15.0</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>convergence</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Literal>0.2</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>passes</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>minObservations</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>maxObservationDistance</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>pixelsPerCell</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>queryBuffer</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>outputBBOX</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:Function>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>outputWidth</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>wms_width</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:Function>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Function name="parameter">
         <ogc:Literal>outputHeight</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>wms_height</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:Function>
       </ogc:Function>
     </ogc:Function>
   </Transformation>
   <Rule>
     <RasterSymbolizer>
       <!-- specify geometry attribute of input to pass validation -->
       <Geometry><ogc:PropertyName>point</ogc:PropertyName></Geometry>
       <Opacity>0.8</Opacity>
       <ColorMap type="ramp" >
         <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="-990" label="nodata" opacity="0"/>
         <ColorMapEntry color="#2E4AC9" quantity="-9" label="values"/>
         <ColorMapEntry color="#41A0FC" quantity="-6" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#58CCFB" quantity="-3" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#76F9FC" quantity="0" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#6AC597" quantity="2" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#479364" quantity="4" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#2E6000" quantity="6" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#579102" quantity="8" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#9AF20C" quantity="10" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#B7F318" quantity="12" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#DBF525" quantity="14" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#FAF833" quantity="16" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#F9C933" quantity="18" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#F19C33" quantity="20" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#ED7233" quantity="22" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#EA3F33" quantity="24" label="values" />
         <ColorMapEntry color="#BB3026" quantity="40" label="values" />
       </ColorMap>
       </RasterSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
     <Transformation>
            <ogc:Function name="ras:Contour">
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>ff</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>-5</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>15</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>30</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
     </Transformation>
     <Rule>
       <Name>rule1</Name>
       <Title>Contour Line</Title>
       <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </LineSymbolizer>
       <TextSymbolizer>
         <Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
         </Label>
         <Font>
           <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
         </Font>
         <LabelPlacement>
           <LinePlacement/>
         </LabelPlacement>
         <Halo>
           <Radius>
             <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
           </Radius>
           <Fill>
             <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
             <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
           </Fill>
         </Halo>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
         <Priority>2000</Priority>
         <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
         <VendorOption name="repeat">100</VendorOption>
         <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
         <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
       </TextSymbolizer>
     </Rule>
   </FeatureTypeStyle>
   </UserStyle>
 </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The first part of the code works! The result of that is the image shown above. But the second part, the contour part, is not working. If I try to preview it on the layer I get the following message: [image]

I think the way I am doing this is wrong, but there is not really a good example online that shows how it should be done. Or at least I have not found that yet..

Answer (score 1):

You can read this [tutorial](https://boundlessgeo.com/2013/01/chaining-rendering-transformations-in-geoserver/) describing the approach.

The issue is with the `contour` section. As it is, the original point data is used. Instead, you would need to give it the `Barne Surface` output. To do so, within the `countour` data section, re-compute the `Barne Surface`

```
<Transformation>
    <ogc:Function name="ras:Contour">
      <ogc:Function name="parameter">
        <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Function name="vec:BarnesSurface">
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>valueAttr</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>ff</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>scale</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>15.0</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>convergence</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>0.2</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>passes</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>minObservations</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>maxObservationDistance</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>pixelsPerCell</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>queryBuffer</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>40</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>outputBBOX</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Function name="env">
                        <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
                     </ogc:Function>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>outputWidth</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Function name="env">
                        <ogc:Literal>wms_width</ogc:Literal>
                     </ogc:Function>
                   </ogc:Function>
                   <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                     <ogc:Literal>outputHeight</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Function name="env">
                        <ogc:Literal>wms_height</ogc:Literal>
                     </ogc:Function>
                   </ogc:Function>
                 </ogc:Function>

      </ogc:Function>
      <ogc:Function name="parameter">
        <ogc:Literal>ff</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>-5</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>15</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>30</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Function>
</Transformation>
```

Comment: Thanks! I hope this works. Will let you know. Just one more question: Is it wise to do this in the same SLD, or maybe in separate SLD-files (creating different layers). What do you think? Since you have to compute the Barnes Surface again I don't see the need to do this in the same SLD-file.

Comment: It's up to you. It might be easier to manage should you want to change a parameter if they are both in the same file. Personally, I would write a new transformation that returns the surface and its contour so it is computed once only.

Comment: I am fairly new to the geo-world and writing a new transformation is not something I can do yet. But thanks for the advice :)

Comment: The code for making contour lines still does not work. When I put the code in a separate SLD-file I get the following message: 'Parameter ff is not among the process parameters: [data, brand, levels...etc]'. But I need this in the code for the Barness Surface. When it is not inside the contour transformation it works fine.