# It is possible to create a raster map using a vector dataset in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, interpolation

I need to create a map of pressure shades using a point data set having each point its value of pressure. So I need to give a color to each point based on its pressure value. But after that I need the spaces between points to be fill with the interpolation color between every four points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** Yes, use the [Barnes Surface](https://github.com/planetfederal/suite/blob/master/docs/usermanual/source/cartography/rt/barnes.rst) or [Heat Map](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#heatmap-generation) vector-to-raster processes, but it is a [bad idea to do this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/304737/79).

Unless, you really want to generate a different map with every request (and why would you want to do that?) then this is a bad idea as edge effects and slight differences in bounding boxes will lead to strange effects. For example, here is a tiled heat map of the US population.

[image]

What you really, want to do is use QGis or some other desktop system to make a raster using any of the many [interpolation methods](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html) and then add the resulting fixed raster to GeoServer.

Comment: You were right, what I really wanted was to create a raster storing in each band the data to be visualized